# MySQL --- SELECT query that meets criteria across multiple tuples

Tags: mysql

I have created the following simple table to illustrate the problem we are trying to solve:

```
  CREATE TABLE soPost
  (
    id    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    code  INT,
    value VARCHAR(8),

    PRIMARY KEY(id)
  );
```

The table has been populated with the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO soPost(code, value)
VALUES (101, 'XYZ'), (101, 'ABC'), (101, 'DEF'), (101, 'GHI'),
       (201, 'XYZ'), (201, 'ABC'), (201, 'JKL'),
       (301, 'XYZ'), (301, 'DEF'), (301, 'MNO'),
       (401, 'XYZ'), (401, 'PRQ'),
       (501, 'STU'), (501, 'VWZ');
```

The result of

```
SELECT * FROM soPost;
```

is:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | code | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |  101 | XYZ   |
|  2 |  101 | ABC   |
|  3 |  101 | DEF   |
|  4 |  101 | GHI   |
|  5 |  201 | XYZ   |
|  6 |  201 | ABC   |
|  7 |  201 | JKL   |
|  8 |  301 | XYZ   |
|  9 |  301 | DEF   |
| 10 |  301 | MNO   |
| 11 |  401 | XYZ   |
| 12 |  401 | PRQ   |
| 13 |  501 | STU   |
| 14 |  501 | VWZ   |
+----+------+-------+
```

We need to select codes where at least one of the values is “XYZ” but none of the values is “ABC” or “DEF”.  Obviously the only value that meets this criteria is code 401.

Kindly suggest the SQL query to realize this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` subquery to perform this test:

```
SELECT code 
FROM soPost s1
WHERE s1.value = 'XYZ' AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM soPost s2 
              WHERE s2.code = s1.code AND s2.value IN('ABC', 'DEF'))
```

Output:

```
code
401
```

Comment: @Strawberry other than being shorter any particular reason to change the OR clause to an IN?

Comment: Well, it's more scalable, isn't it - I mean if you start adding more values

Comment: @Strawberry fair comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use subdataset :

`select distinct(code) from soPost

where 
    code not in (
        select distinct(code) from soPost where value = "ABC" or value = "DEF"
    ) 
    and 
    code in (
        select code from soPost where value='XYZ'
    );`

Comment: Note that distinct is not a function